# ClickOnce files are overwritten after update

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

My clickonce application contains a file with data. Its build action is set to Content with "copy to output dir if newer". User will change this data file while using the application. After making a clickonce update, this file gets overwritten by the original file. 
What can I do to avoid this? If I set the publishing option of this file to "exlude" or "data file" user's file gets deleted. If I set the option to "included" user's file gets overwritten.

Is there any quick solution to this problem, apart from dynamically creating a second file (obviously not in the output directory) at first startup and store the file data there?

Comment: Why is there such a file? What purpose does it fulfil? If its a settings file, consider using user.config settings. Think about storing the file in your assembly as a resource then copying it out when you startup.

Comment: It's a local highscore file as the application is a game. I consider now to use a directory in AppData to store it.

Comment: Look at user.config settings.